# Return street name from jquery addresspicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the addpresspicker

[link to ui.addresspicker.js](https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker/blob/master/src/jquery.ui.addresspicker.js)

and i have gotten everything to work as expected. I have gotten the results returned into each individual section as in the demo

> xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html

but am missing the Street Name.

I am using this as a means of providing the correct address on a webform and those details need to be formatted into a CSV file ready to be imported to another program after the form is submitted.

What's the better way to do this? As every address is different each time, i'm not sure running validation on the full address to extract the street name and type (e.g First Street) would be my best option.

I found another post on here that looks like it returns the street name (long_name component) using a JSON call to the google maps API but assumes you have the lat and long already then extracts the street name from that but I can't find the question now to reference it.

Example shown below. I want to be able to separate Park Avenue and have it put in the street name box.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/prFGD.jpg

SOLVED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any sample code so a guess of what you're missing is in the options when you initialize the extension. Add a value for the route element and assign it the id of the element for the street name in your page.

```
elements: {
       :
      route: #add-the-id-of-your-element-here,
       :
  },
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had misspelled the id of the element assigned to output the route into. After looking at it again as per you're post i realised my error.